# Get username of a thread

Tags: windows, security, user-accounts, threads

- How to gather the `username/SID/account` of a particular thread?

No, **I am not looking for account of the process**, but of specific thread.

I've looked-up Process Explorer, but it doesn't show security-context or user details anywhere for the running threads.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic here. Maybe try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not asking software recommendation, some technique to find username of a thread. I saw many answers (high-rated) of you are on software recommendations (on this site only).

Comment: Your first 3 words of your post is `"using which tool"`? And you also write `Any built-in, or third party utility would be okay for me.`. Sure seems like a software recommendation to me

Answer (score 0):

> A great tool to witness Impersonation is [Process Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/processesandthreads/processmonitor.mspx). This tool logs all access to files and registry at the time of access, therefore we see a snapshot of the impersonating thread before it reverts back to the primary token.

Taken from [What’s in a Token (Part 2): Impersonation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/01/11/what-s-in-a-token-part-2-impersonation.aspx).